# Unicode expression @"\p{Lt}" is not matching with a title case string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to validate a title case string "Sam And Will" using the unicode expression \p{Lt}. But the expression isn't matching the string. Is there any alternative for this. Please help. Thank you.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("Sam And Will", @"\p{Lt}");
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
 Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Titlecase and uppercase-as-first-character are [different things](http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#4):

> **Q: What is titlecase? How is it different from uppercase?**
> ....
>
> The titlecase mapping in Unicode differs from the uppercase mapping in that a number of characters require special handling. These are chiefly ligatures and digraphs such as 'fl', 'dz', and 'lj', plus a number of polytonic Greek characters. For example, U+01C7 (LJ) maps to U+01C8 (Lj) rather than to U+01C9 (lj).

If you add a [digraph `Dz`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dz_(digraph))

```
char c = '\u01F2';
```

to the source string (no matter at the beginning of a word or not), it will be found by `@"\p{Lt}"`.

BTW, just to illustrate the difference, if you assign a string

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
string s = c + " " + char.ToLower(c, ci) + " " + char.ToUpper(c);
```

the value will be

```
"ǲ ǳ Ǳ" // Dz - titlecase, dz - lowercase, DZ - uppercase
```

---

For your task, consider something like this:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(@"Sam And Will", @"\b(\p{Lu})\p{Ll}*\b");
foreach (Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```